# switch_to.frame for win32com

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I am trying to automate the browser using win32.
Selenium cannot be used because of the information security of the company.

Faced a problem, I can't switch to another iframe in win32. All elements are only in the first frame.
Perhaps someone knows a method for switching the frame?

```
ie = win32com.client.Dispatch("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Visible = 1

ie.Navigate(url)

time.sleep(5)

frames = ie.Document.Body.getElemenetsByTagName('iframe')
```

`frames` has only 1 element, but there are more.

Comment: Is `getElemnetsByTagName` a typo in your code or just when you copied it over to SO? Also: Why is it tagged VBA?

Comment: Typo in SO.
I'll remove the VBA tag, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Example of how you might switch between iframes using the `InternetExplorer.Application` object:

```
import win32com.client
import time

ie = win32com.client.Dispatch("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = 1

url = "your_url_here"
ie.Navigate(url)

while ie.Busy:
    time.sleep(1)

doc = ie.Document

frames = doc.getElementsByTagName("iframe")
print("Number of iframes:", len(frames))

iframe = frames[0]
doc.parentWindow.frameElement = iframe
```

Comment: doc.getElementsByTagName("iframe") throws error "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"